# How to return contact and account in a single method

Tags: apexrest, trailhead

In Salesforce Trailhead there is one Challenge available. Please find the challenge description below

create an Apex REST class that is accessible at '`/Accounts/<Account_ID>/contacts`'. The service will return the account's ID and Name plus the ID and Name of all contacts associated with the account. Write unit tests that achieve 100% code coverage for the class and run your Apex tests.

- The Apex class must be called 'AccountManager'.
- The Apex class must have a method called 'getAccount' that is
  annotated with @HttpGet
- The method must return the ID and Name for the requested record and
  all associated contacts with their ID and Name.

Based on last condition how can I return account and contact from same method ?
I returned Account object alone. but it throws the following exception.

**MyCode:**

```
Account result =  [SELECT ID,Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId];
return result;
```

**Exception :**

```
There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: 
System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
```

Comment: Can u post your code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will return a Account with contacts in same list.

Your SOQL should have inner query for contacts linked with account .

**Code :**

```
Account acc = [select id ,name ,(select id ,Name from contacts) from Account ];
```

When you return acc.contacts will hold contact list as well

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

Account[] acc = [select id ,name ,(select id ,Name from contacts) from Account ];

or

List acc = [select id ,name ,(select id ,Name from contacts) from Account ];

as u didnt hold the indefinite data in a list it showed u the exception